# Pivot on a column with a big number o values crashes browser

Tags: ag-grid

We are experiencing an issue when trying to pivot on a column which has a big number of distinct values. In this specific case the issue is that K = N, where N is the total amount of rows in this case 10k rows, and K the number of distinct values on which the pivoting is done.

When trying to pivot on the specific column with K distinct values, the browser ends up crashing.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue before?

I would expect it would work, but then again probably it is a limitation on the browser's tab memory.
At least having an API which is similar to `onColumnPivotChanged` but would be more like `onColumnPivotWillChange` which would allow us to determine the number of columns by calling `getPivotResultColumns` and perhaps interrupt the user action if it is above a treshold.